# How to make it that it will show an echo

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a forum kinda thing to practice my skills but I am struggling with making it display the right things. Down here you see my code with explanation with what I want and what I have.

This code will display the list of boards:

```
<?php
  $boardds = $app->get_boards();
  foreach ($boardds as $board) {
   if($board['url'] == $url[1]){
    $actiefboardid = $board['id'];
    echo '<li style="background-color:lightgray;"><a href=""'.$board['url'].'">' . $board['topic'] . '</a></li>';
    } else {
     echo '<li><a href="'.$board['url'].'">' . $board['topic'] . '</a></li>'; 
    }

  }
?>
```

After that later in the code I am displaying all the 'topics' based on which board we are on, like this:

```
<?php
  echo "<div class='tab-pane' id='activity'>";
  echo "<div class='post clearfix'>";
  $toppic = $app->get_topics($actiefboardid); <--- here I am displaying the records based on $actiefboardid
  foreach($toppic as $topic){
    echo "<div class='user-block'>";
       if(file_exists('assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'])) { ..... ect
```

Now I want it to show something like " There are no topics at this board" when there are no records for that board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) condition like below:-

```
$toppic = $app->get_topics($actiefboardid);

if(count($toppic)>0){

  foreach($topic as $topic){
   //your code
  }
}else{

  echo "There are no topics on this board";
}
```

***Code need be something like this:-***

```
<?php
    $boardds = $app->get_boards();
    if(isset($url[1])){
        foreach ($boardds as $board) {
            if($board['url'] == $url[1]){
                $actiefboardid = $board['id'];
                echo '<li style="background-color:lightgray;"><a href=""'.$board['url'].'">' . $board['topic'] . '</a></li>';
            } else {
                echo '<li><a href="'.$board['url'].'">' . $board['topic'] . '</a></li>'; 
            }
        }
    }else{
      echo "Please provide url 1";
    }
?>
```

And:-

```
<?php
    echo "<div class='tab-pane' id='activity'>";
    echo "<div class='post clearfix'>";
    if(isset($actiefboardid)){
        $toppic = $app->get_topics($actiefboardid); <--- here I am displaying the records based on $actiefboardid
        if(count($toppic) > 0){
            foreach($toppic as $topic){
                echo "<div class='user-block'>";
                if(file_exists('assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'])) { //..... ect

                }
            }
        }
    }
```